# error on request when using spring security

Tags: angular, spring-boot, spring-security

I am programming an angular springboot application. Before using Spring security, everything worked fine; when I was displaying the home page a request was made to get a list of ProduitImmobilier

```
  loadData() {
    console.log('LOADDATA is called');
    Object.keys(this.search).forEach(key => key = null);
    this.search.page = 1;
    this.search.pageSize = 5;
    this.requestService.getListProduitImmobilierDTO(this.search).subscribe(
      articles => {this.annonces = articles;
                   this.collectionSize = articles[0].collectionSize; },
      (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        console.log('before display error');
        console.log(err);
        console.log('after display error');
      }
    );
  }
```

and here is the requestService

```
  getListProduitImmobilierDTO(search: Search): Observable<ProduitImmobilierDTO[]> {
    const headers: HttpHeaders = new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *', 'utf-8');
    const options = { headers };
    // tslint:disable-next-line: max-line-length
    return this.http.post<Search>('/api/produitimmobilier/all', JSON.stringify(search), options).pipe(map((search1: Search) => search1.result as ProduitImmobilierDTO[]));
  }
```

But, when I added Spring Security facility, the request sent an error back
here is an extract of the configuration

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http         
    .headers()
     .frameOptions().sameOrigin()
     .and()
       .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/**/*.scss", "/**/*.js","/**/*.html").permitAll()
           .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
           .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
           .anyRequest().authenticated()
           .and()
       .formLogin()
           .loginPage("/api/user/login?login=1")
           .defaultSuccessUrl("/")
           .failureUrl("/")
           .permitAll()
           .and()
       .logout()
        .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
        .logoutSuccessUrl("/")
        .deleteCookies("my-remember-me-cookie")
           .permitAll()
           .and()
        .rememberMe()
         //.key("my-secure-key")
         .rememberMeCookieName("my-remember-me-cookie")
         .tokenRepository(persistentTokenRepository())
         .tokenValiditySeconds(24 * 60 * 60)
         .and()
       .exceptionHandling()
       .and()
       .csrf().disable();
}
```

The former request I talked about then sent back a 302 code error

```
HEADER
URL de la requête : http://localhost:4200/api/produitimmobilier/all
Méthode de la requête : POST
Adresse distante : 127.0.0.1:4200
Code d’état :302
Version : HTTP/1.1

RESPONSE
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data
```

When I display the error from angular by this extract of code

```
      (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        console.log('before display error');
        console.log(err);
        console.log('after display error');
      }
```

I get the following output

```
error: SyntaxError: "JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data"
......
message: "Http failure during parsing for http://localhost:8080/api/user/login?login=1"
name: "HttpErrorResponse"
ok: false
status: 200
statusText: "OK"
url: "http://localhost:8080/api/user/login?login=1"
```

First of all, I don't understand why and how Spring Security redirect th request to the loginForm url

Globally how to correct the error ?

I must add that a use a proxy on angular app side
proxy.config.js

```
{
  "/api/*": {

    "target":  {
       "host": "localhost",
       "protocol": "http:",
       "port": 8080
     },
    "secure": false,
     "changeOrigin": true,
     "logLevel": "info"
  }
}
```

and I add corMappings on back-end side

```
/**
 * CORS configuration
 */
@Override
public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
    registry.addMapping("/**")
            .allowedOrigins(
                    "http://localhost:4200"
            )
            .allowedMethods(
                    "GET",
                    "PUT",
                    "POST",
                    "DELETE",
                    "PATCH",
                    "OPTIONS"
            );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found how to correct the wrong behavior. It was sufficient to add the line

```
.antMatchers("/**/*").permitAll()
```

in

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http         
    .headers()
     .frameOptions().sameOrigin()
     .and()
       .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/**/*.scss", "/**/*.js","/**/*.html").permitAll()
           .antMatchers("/**/*").permitAll()
           .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
           .anyRequest().authenticated()
           .and()
       .formLogin()
           .loginPage("/api/user/login")
           .defaultSuccessUrl("/")
           .failureUrl("/")
           .permitAll()
           .and()
       .logout()
```